# Can`t get any data from COM Port in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, port

I`m using GUI to work with data

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ //Button reaction
            try {
                serialPort.openPort();
                serialPort.setParams(
                        SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
```

Here is **Listener** to get information from port

```
private class EventListener implements SerialPortEventListener {
        public String receivedData;
        public String noDataFromPort;

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
                try {
                    receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                    textField.setText(receivedData);
                    textArea.setText(receivedData + "\n");
                    serialPort.closePort();
                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    noDataFromPort = "No data received";
                    textField.setText(noDataFromPort + " " + ex);
                    textArea.setText(noDataFromPort + " " + ex + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

                serialPort.setFlowControlMode(
                        SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN |
                        SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
```

**Mask** for port

```
serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener(), serialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
                    //serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener());
                    serialPort.writeString("R"); // Data for scale(R- get data from device)

                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    portOpenFail = "Port"+ " " + serialPort.getPortName()+ " " + "not found" + " " + ex;
                }
```

Here i`m trying to input information from port

```
try {
                    textField.setText(fromPort = serialPort.readString());
                    textField.setText(fromPort + s);
                    textField.setText(fromPort);
                    textArea.append(fromPort + s + "\n");
                } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                    textField.setText("No Data from " + serialPort.getPortName());
                    textArea.setText("No Data from " + serialPort.getPortName() + "\n");
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format and indent the code properly. It looks like some of the code is out of order, and notes seem to interrupt the code flow.

Comment: Here is a link to full class https://gist.github.com/Liovorn/a5d7a51c2ca6ca36d845904c76ea124f